# Unable to follow link to wrongly flagged answer

Tags: support, declined-flags, deleted-questions, not-an-answer

Some days ago (maybe October 17th or 18th), I flagged [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773840/software-for-face-recognition/46774004#46774004) as "not an answer" 
As far as I remember it consisted of some friendly words plus a link, and in my opinion it should have been a comment because without the link it seemed quite useless.

This flag was declined, which is ok because I *was* a bit uncertain if I was being too strict.

My problem is that if I want to flag something now, I get the prompt to review the declined flag before proceeding.

[image]

But if I click on the link I can't see the wrongly flagged post: it seems that the question to which the answer belongs has been deleted.

I'm sorry if this question does not belong here but my attempts to find out what to do by googling the keywords "stack overflow flag declined review" resulted only in my having to prove to some script that I am able to recognize cars and roadsigns.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the prompt?

Comment: The flag will still show up in your flag list, even if the question has been deleted.  Did you look far enough down the flag list to see it; it might not be right at the top after all.

Comment: @Servy - the flag is topmost in my flag list but if I click on it I get a "Page not found". Maybe I have too little rep to see deleted posts?

Comment: Then everything is working as designed.  You need 10k rep to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is sub-optimal UX.

What happened was, the moderator declined your "not an answer" flag on the answer, but deleted the question. So, since you do not have [sufficient privileges to see deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you cannot see either the question *or* its answer(s).

The question was asking for a recommendation of software to do face recognition, which is off-topic because we don't do recommendations. The question was closed on that basis; in fact, yours was the final vote that caused it to be closed. That was the correct choice.

The *answer* was merely recommending software to do face recognition. Now, granted, this does not make for a very good answer, but it *did* answer the question that was asked, so a "not an answer" flag is not appropriate. (See also: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer))

In cases like this, moderation attention needs to be directed at the problematic question, which is creating an opportunity for answers like this to be posted. You addressed that by closing, and the moderator who reviewed your NAA flag addressed that by *deleting* the closed question (which removed all of the problematic content, including the answer).

Of course, it's very hard for you to figure any of this out without being able to review the post you flagged, and the system asking you to do it when you cannot is one of those "broken by design" things.

Comment: All right, so I'll wait to click the link until I get 10k rep. But if I have another flag declined in the next two or three years, I will only notice by looking in my flag list, because I will get used to the prompt. That's maybe not as it should be, because this way the site loses a means of communicating with users. -  Thanks anyway for the explanation and the  links. (I may have gotten better at flagging correctly but I know I'm far from perfect.)

Comment: The warning will go away once you have a helpful flag or two, @0X0nosugar. But yes, I agree with you that this is not the best possible design. It would be nice if we had some way to make an exception and show you posts that you flagged, even if they had been deleted. Unfortunately, that's a brand new feature, and not likely to be implemented any time soon.

Comment: Hey, they [added the ability to see deleted reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266868) a few years ago. If people keep asking to see deleted posts they flagged, maybe Oded will get inspired again.